# Class Recognition; R.drawable.balloons

Tags: android, r.java-file

Okay, I seem to be having a small issue with R.drawable.balloons. I'm trying to use a template for building a private external storage file that I found on Android Developer, but balloons keeps giving an error (cannot be resolved or is not a field). I was wondering if I could get some help fixing it.

Here's the code section it sits in:

```
void createExternalStoragePrivateFile() {
        // Create a path where we will place our private file on external
        // storage.
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "DemoFile.jpg");

    try {
            /*  
                Very simple code to copy a picture from the application's
                resource into the external file.  Note that this code does
                no error checking, and assumes the picture is small (does not
                try to copy it in chunks).  Note that if external storage is
                not currently mounted this will silently fail.
            */

            //  Creates file to stream picture
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //  Allows app to accept the picture
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.balloons);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);
        os.write(data);
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
            // not currently mounted.
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
}
```

A heads up, in case I get called out for being a copy/paster, this is only supposed to be a template, but I would like to test that it works before I make changes. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need an image named `balloons` in the `res\drawable` folder of your project (or any of its variants, such as `drawable-hdpi`, &c). The `R` class is autogenerated.

See [How do I add R drawable android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980621/how-do-i-add-r-drawable-android)